# Get the IP address of google.com

Tags: code-golf, internet

## Challenge

In this simple challenge, you have to print the public IP address of `google.com`.

## Rules

- You have to output either the IPv6 or IPv4 address, and do it by somehow using internet.
- Output does not strictly need to be the IP address, your answer will be valid if the correct IP address is somewhere in the output, like `Hello - google.com - 142.250.67.78` is a valid output.
- You can use DNS queries and any kind of web APIs or web scraping.
- Standard loopholes apply, except usage of URL shorteners, wanna see how creative you can get ;-)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! As it is, this seems like a reasonably well-written challenge. However, in future, I'd recommend posting in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback first

Comment: Also, `google.com` has quite a lot of IP addresses. Presumably we should output just one of them

Comment: @pxeger yes only one of them!

Comment: Crap, there's no golfing language based on Batch / Bash.

Comment: "standard loopholes apply, except usage of URL shorteners" - does this mean we can or we can't use URL shorteners?

Comment: @pxeger I think, url shorteners allowed (though who needs it here)

Comment: I’ve removed the point about banning a literal interpretation of the task, as that’s a standard loophole, so you don’t need to worry about that

Comment: _your answer will be valid if the correct IP address is somewhere in the output_  This means you can print all IP adresses and call it done. Quite boring. Also, _somehow usig the Internet_ is too vague

Comment: I've voted to close because there is still confusion over how many IP addresses may appear in the output. OP's comment above ('yes only one of them') seems to imply that there must *only* be one, but there is a contradiction with the second rule ('your answer will be valid if the correct IP address is somewhere in the output') that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Would you mind if the rule is changed to "You have to output at least one IP address of Google.com, and there must be no more than 1000 different IP addresses in the output"?

Answer (score 13):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 40 bytes

```sh
echo {0..255}.{0..255}.{0..255}.{0..255}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX6HaQE/PyNS0Vg834/9/AA)

Since the output only needs to *contain* the IP address, we can just enumerate all of them! This probably isn't the shortest option, but it's funny!

Comment: Dosen't work when I click TIO link ;-(

Comment: `and do it by somehow using internet.`

Comment: (I just came up with the same idea... (besides this is not in the standard loophole, but yes I agree that the output format is a little too liberal)) @2x-1 That's not an issue, just add a ping to a.com.

Comment: Perhaps "the output should not contain more than 10^6 IP addresses".

Answer (score 7):

### Windows Batch, 15 bytes

```
ping google.com
```

#### Example run

```
C:\>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [8.7.198.46] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 8.7.198.46:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: "ping gogle.com" will shave you off another byte!

Comment: @ChrisB: "ping goo.gl" will shave you off 3 other bytes!

Answer (score 6):

## Bash, 14 bytes

Requires `dnsutils`.

```bash
dig google.com
```

Comment: `dig goo.gl` saves 4

Comment: "except usage of URL shorteners" seems to imply you cannot use `goo.gl`

Comment: @ijustlovemath I think that is given in the OP as an exception to the standard loopholes - i.e. "You may use URL shorteners even if that is a standard loophole, all other standard loopholes apply".

Comment: Well, if shortened URLs are ok: ```dig g.co```

Comment: Except both `goo.gl` and `g.co` point to different IP addresses than `google.com`, so neither actually works.

Comment: @Neinstein goo.gl, g.co and google.com all point to the same IP address for me.  Are you sure you're not being fooled by a CDN?

Comment: @Neinstein: google.com seems to have different IPs anyway, depending who's asking. The important thing is that the returned IP for `g.co` or `goo.gl` leads to `google.com` when typed in the browser.

Comment: With Google we're definitely talking about multiple IP *ranges* not just separate IPs. It's almost an ISP at this point as it's already providing Cloud services, DNS, etc. Add load balancers and different datacenters and you have multiple IPs at worst and full ranges at best.

Comment: All three ```goo.gl```, ```g.co```, and ```google.com``` point to servers with content _controlled_ by Google, but what is the actual test? Getting an IP that serves the Google search engine homepage to a web browser? If that's the case, then yes, these three are not equivalent.

Comment: @spuck: Should it read "these three are equivalent"? Because the returned IPs lead to Google search engine for the 3 mentioned domains.

Comment: @EricDuminil, I meant they are not equivalent from my perspective; visiting the three domain names in my web browser takes me to different web pages, but the DNS lookups from all three names can return the same IP, which is the original challenge.

Comment: @spuck: It seems to be the case, yes.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 47 bytes

```java
v->java.net.InetAddress.getByName("google.com")
```

[(Don't) try it online](https://tio.run/##jY@xCsJADIZ3nyI4XQfvBURBQdDBOogu4nBeY716TUovrYr47PWk4iwkgX/4fr4UpjWjIrt21psQYG0cPQcAjgTrs7EI6ScCbE4FWgGr9uwyaBOQS823AEXkNaHoHV2Jb7TkIIu7xUoc0ziir7hxghhxFlIgmHTtaPrjVvHMsqzGEHSOMn@kpkQ1zJlzj9pyOUw6gHHfUjUnH1u@Ze1HpYzGaiu1o/xwBPOfWP/T9hEES82N6Cry4kmRtooa75Okd391bw) (local run outputs `google.com/142.250.179.206`).

**Explanation:**

```java
v->                          // Method with empty unused parameter & InetAddress return
  java.net.InetAddress       //  Create and return an InetAddress-instance
    .getByName("google.com") //  for hostname "google.com"
```

When this `InetAddress`-instance is printed, it will use [its `InetAddress.html#toString()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#toString()) by default, which prints in the format `hostname / literal IP address`.

Comment: Also works for Kotlin, I think.

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell 5, 26 bytes

```
resolve-dnsname google.com
```

luckily, powershell has a CMDlet for this!

Somehow this does not work on TIO, but on powershell 5

```
Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
google.com                                     AAAA   149   Answer     2404:6800:4007:805::200e
google.com                                     A      273   Answer     142.250.67.78
```

[image]

Comment: `test-connection google.com` is an equal-bytes alternative.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen nice find

Comment: TIO uses a sandbox environment, which doesn’t allow internet connections, which is probably why it doesn’t work

Comment: It's a shell. You can also use nslookup

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
require'resolv';Resolv.getaddress'goo.gl'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyi1sDSzKFW9KLU4P6dM3ToITOulp5YkpqQABYvV0/Pz9dJz1P//BwA)

Or as an alternative:

`dig goo.gl`

`wget goo.gl`

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (`-m32`), 67 bytes

To avoid having to include any header files, I flatten the structure and manually dereference the first entry of the `h_addr_list` member of the `hostent` structure. Replace `google.com` with `localhost` to test in tio.run.

```c
f(){puts(inet_ntoa(**(((int***)gethostbyname("google.com"))[4])));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsMgEAC/suTkCkmg7S1PKaVaa4ygboibhhLy9Vp76nFgZkzrjCl9D4udgzYWlCNywXaGooLN8wQqkNFhoswKmIBtZvAJ2FO3rKmMAvd55Sx8snxPTFpIKURFllKis/xLH@@koxXN/94gXi83RByOUl2I2ifxIv9E2KFOBzjKx4xBu1zaeD6VdvsC)

Comment: Anything with triple pointers gets an upvote in my estimation :)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + dnsutils, 15 bytes

```
host google.com
```

Comment: `dig google.com`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 20 bytes

```
<?=`ping google.co`;
```

For some reason `google.co` returns exactly the same IP as `google.com`.

Comment: you can also change it to goo.gl

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB/Octave, 26 bytes

```
resolvehost goo.gl address
```

This solution uses [`resolvehost`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/resolvehost.html) which is part of the Instrumentation Toolbox ([`instrument-control`](https://wiki.octave.org/Instrument_control_package) in Octave). We provide a second input (`'address'`) to specify that we want the IP address.

Also we avoid using parentheses because both inputs should be interpreted as strings already so we can save 5 bytes by not using parentheses, quotes, and commas:

Long form: `resolvehost('goo.gl','address')`

Notes:

- On Octave at least, we cannot shorten `address` (in many MATLAB/Octave commands you can shorten string literals). I don't have MATLAB available to me with this toolbox so it's possible this could be shortened in MATLAB.
- We could alternately use the second output without a second input: `[,a]=resolvehost('goo.gl')` which would be the same length as this answer but we have to use parentheses and quotes. Also the empty first output is only valid in Octave. In MATLAB we would have to do `[~,a]=resolvehost('goo.gl')` which is 1 byte longer.

Answer (score 2):

### Golang, 77 bytes

```
package main;import(."net";."fmt");func main(){Print(LookupIP("google.com"))}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 23 Bytes

```
HostLookup["google.co"]
```

Like with most things in life, Mathematica/Wolfram Language has a builtin for it. Requires version 11 or above.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <s>164 bytes</s> 127 bytes

```
base64 -d<<<3dYBIAABAAAAAAABBmdvb2dsZQNjb20AAAEAAQAAKRAAAAAAAAAMAAoACCjxxt05OkuU|nc 1.1.1.1 -u 53|hexdump -e '4/1 "%0.2d.""\n"'
```

Why use `dig` when you can use netcat.

Example Run:

```
221.214.129.128.
00.01.00.01.
00.00.00.01.
06.103.111.111.
103.108.101.03.
99.111.109.00.
00.01.00.01.
192.12.00.01.
00.01.00.00.
01.29.00.04.
142.250.182.238. //Google's IP
00.00.41.04.
208.00.00.00.
```

EDIT: Saved a lot of bytes thanks to @DigitalTrauma

Comment: For people who want to know more about [DNS](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall16/compsci356/DNS/DNS-primer.pdf) protocol.

Comment: Bash only, no utils: ```exec 9<>/dev/tcp/api.hackertarget.com/80 ; echo -e "GET /dnslookup/?q=google.com HTTP/1.1\nHost: api.hackertarget.com\n" >&9 ; cat <&9```

Comment: @spuck haha nice.

Comment: You can base64 encode your request datagram to save several bytes.  Also herestrings help: `base64 -d<<<3dYBIAABAAAAAAABBmdvb2dsZQNjb20AAAEAAQAAKRAAAAAAAAAMAAoACCjxxt05OkuU|nc 1.1.1.1 -u 53|hexdump -e '4/1 "%0.2d.""\n"'`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

-4 bytes by Arnauld, who got better reading skills than me...

```python
from socket import*
print(gethostbyname('google.com'))
```

Comment: Oh, good catch Arnauld, thank you! Missed that somehow..

Comment: import socket as s;s.gethostbyname('g.co') if in console, otherwise with print. Perhaps google.com if shortener is disallowed.

Comment: `import socket as s;s.` is one byte more than `from socket import*;`.
Shorteners are not allowed according to the question.

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML](https://smlnj.org/sml97.html), 35 bytes

```ml
OS.Process.system"ping google.com";
```

I never used it before, but it turns out there is a [`OS` structure](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/os.html#OS:SIG:SPEC) in the basis library which lets you execute arbitrary commands in the system's default shell.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Batch, 19 bytes

```
nslookup google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 57 bytes

A full program that prints the first A record (IPv4).

```javascript
require('dns').lookup('google.com',(_,s)=>console.log(s))
```

[(Don't) Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjRDYAgDAXAcdomyAa6iiFACIo8pOL66H3e4V6nvuf2LBUhztnjPXKPTKEqiS3AORpTAlKJ1uMiw7tRWTePqvivILGKzPkB)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 44 bytes

A function that prints the IP among other things

```cs
_=>System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com")
```

[Can't Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqMQXFlckpqr55daoucZ4JFfXOKaV1JUaaeQBlShYPs/3tYOSYVLXrGee2oJXJmGUnp@fnpOql5yfq6S5n9rLq6AIqCpGiDNGgaamtb/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Visual Basic .NET (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <del>60</del> 53 bytes

```vb
Console.WriteLine(Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsIwEIDhPU8ROiWDeQepRQUVIYNzEo8aSO4kdxX69FE7/cvP94m7RA36ub6pCWu/skBV9yWWnPRYArPeK/8KDZ7aL1FfQ0Zj@0jIVMA9Wha4ZARzA3EHZHcEORHLhNJWM8xE829LVAdr@4Qbov7d7P4F)

-7 bytes thanks to @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Since the System namespace is imported by default, you can shave 7 bytes by removing it: `Console.WriteLine(Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com"))`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 31 bytes

```php
<?=gethostbyname('google.com');
```

[(Cannot) Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42PbUkI7@4JKkyLzE3VUM9PT8/PSdVLzk/V13T@v9/AA)

Works on my localhost, still trying to golf it

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 53 bytes

```perl
say join".",map ord,gethostbyname("google.com")=~/./g
```

[Try it offline](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADArxAmTbDgwOgTfARqgxigBFhYfLr1rmCNlrm5IR4KWYJUyRVB9VIe@02tHyO7hJP0RD4inJTkvL0atGf@qPRAufGyW1gNmB8) with `perl -E'say join".",map ord,gethostbyname("google.com")=~/./g'`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46—47 bytes

```python
from socket import*
getaddrinfo('google.co',0)
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/#) doesn't let me run it, but the Jupyter and normal compiler returns this:

```python
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('173.194.220.100', 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('173.194.220.113', 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('173.194.220.101', 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('173.194.220.102', 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('173.194.220.139', 0)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('173.194.220.138', 0))]
```

While the end result leads to google.com, the .com version of this code would return entirely different ip-ranges. Which would add +1 to the byte amount if you consider this not fair.

Answer (score 0):

## Shell / cURL: 12 bytes

```
curl g.co -v        # 12
curl goo.gl -v      # 14
curl google.co -v   # 17
curl google.com -v  # 18
```

IPs

```
$ nslookup google.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.23.238
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4014:80d::200e

$ nslookup g.co
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   g.co
Address: 172.217.23.238
Name:   g.co
Address: 2a00:1450:4014:80d::200e
```

Comment: I'm not sure `g.co` is going to have the same IP address as `google.com`...it seems to be a separate service, despite being owned by the same company.

Comment: It has because `g.co/g` is basically `google.com` :)

Comment: Most probably they have a pile of services / load balancer with various IPs/ranges and route the traffic internally (would make more sense than to jump over Internet)